# How to remove Asterisk (*) symbol from unsaved window tab in Visual Studio IDE

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2022

I'm using [Auto Save File](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=HRai.AutoSaveFile) extension for Visual Studio IDE 2022. I've set Time Delay to 1sec (like in VSCode). It works great! But flashing every second Asterisk (*) symbol really makes annoying.

How can I remove this symbol from current unsaved window tab?

P.S. I need it for web page 'Hot Reload'.

[image]

Comment: Is your PC so unstable that you need to do this? If it does burst into flames then you will have lost everything unless pushed to your remote git repo :)

Comment: Yes! every VSCode user has "unstable" PC   

Comment: Looks like Microsoft gonna add this feature for all those that has "unstable" PC: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/visual-studio-2022-auto-save-file-feature-suggesti/1453919

Comment: The short answer is "you don't"; the long answer is "why would you want to".

Comment: @Pierre Plourde
short answer: "for hot reload", long answer: "read above article"

Answer (score 0):

In older versions of Visual Studio I seem to remember that the Productivity Power Tool extension allowed you to change the 'dirty file' indicator but not remove it.

To be honest how much work would you loose in 1 second? I would set the auto save for every 5 mins maybe. I'm pretty sure there isn't a way to hide the dirty file indicator (how else would you know your file is dirty?).

Comment: This is not about "how much work would I loose in 1 second"...
Read this, I didn't know about this proposal when I ask question: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/visual-studio-2022-auto-save-file-feature-suggesti/1453919

Comment: Visual Studio 17.1 may add some extra save features, it is in preview at the moment.